# ajax display the table on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is the situation. i have a dropdown menu and when i change its value a query will run and display a table. What i want to achieve is when the page load even without clicking on the dropdown menu the table will appear based on the default selected value of dropdown menu.

here my code.
reservation.php

```
<script>

function showSched(str) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("schedDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="schedDiv">

</div>
```

getuser.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "srdatabase";

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql="SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE speaker = '".$q."' AND reservationstatus = 'approved'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table class='reservations-table'>
<tr>
<th>Speaker</th>
<th>Reservation Date</th>
<th>Reservation Time</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['speaker'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use jquery why you have `window.XMLHttpRequest` in your code?! :(

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of the dropdown menu on page load, and then execute an ajax request with it? If so, it sounds like you've already got a function making the ajax request bound to the `change` event of that dropdown. You can do the same thing, but instead bind it to page load like `$(window).load(fetchTableFunction);` so it executes when the page is loaded. Oh, and I agree with the guy above me - is there a reason you aren't using the $.ajax() method, currently?

Comment: yes that what i want to do but what should put inside the fetchtablefunction? I try to search and do it but i cant. sorry im new to jquery. And about the tags im confused between jquery and ajax. Hope you can show me.